# Tensorflow, extending a tensor in a specified dimension

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I am using the scatter_update function and I run into a dimensionality problem. More precisely:

```
out_res = tf.scatter_update(tf.Variable(out), v_rows, tf.Variable(v))
```

gives:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 4 and 5 for 'ScatterUpdate_16' (op: 'ScatterUpdate') with input shapes: [5,18,9,1], [1,9], [5,4,9,1].
```

I'm guessing that I must expand v_rows to the shape [5,9] for this to work. Any idea on how I can extend it from [1,9] to [5,9] ?

Comment: use `tf.reshape` combined with `tf.tile`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - promote to answer? :)  Thanks!